# CSV parsers and OrderedDictionary

Tags: c#, object-oriented, parsing, css, static

I wrote the following (static) class to read files easily in C#. However, it is a static class, so I wonder if there would be a gain to make it a non static method (and therefore, passing arguments as the separator and the path as attributes of the class).

Besides, the `OrderedDictionary` class may not be a good choice (it is not generic but it preserves the order of the columns), and I don't know if there is a nice workaround for this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.IO;

namespace MySolution.FileUtils
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Various helpers to read through the lines of a file.
    /// </summary>
    public static class LinesEnumerator
    {
        public static string ReadFirstLine(string path)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                return sr.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Enumerates the lines of a file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="path">The path of the file.</param>
        /// <param name="maxLines">The maximum number of lines to read.</param>
        /// <returns>The lines of a file, as a IEnumerable</returns>
        public static IEnumerable<string> LinesReader(string path, int maxLines = Int32.MaxValue)
        {
            string line;
            int lineNumber = 0;
            using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null && lineNumber < maxLines)
                {
                    lineNumber++;
                    yield return line;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reads the lines of a CSV file and enumerates them through a csv file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="path">Path to the CSV file</param>
        /// <param name="separator">Separator used by the CSV file</param>
        /// <returns>A collection of ordered dictionaries, corresponding to the lines of the file</returns>
        public static IEnumerable<OrderedDictionary> DictReaderCSV(string path, char separator)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                string[] header = sr.ReadLine().Split(separator);
                string line = "";
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] splittedLine = line.Split(separator);
                    OrderedDictionary od = new OrderedDictionary();
                    for (int i = 0; i < header.Length; i++)
                        od.Add(header[i], splittedLine[i]);
                    yield return od;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180 for details on format, quotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Naming Items**

You should avoid abbreviations like `Dict` in `DictReaderCSV`, spelling it `Dictionary` is cleaner.

Next, it's much more natural to use nouns for class names and verbs for methods. As such, I would name your class `CSVDictionaryReader` and your main method `EnumerateEntries()`. `LinesEnumerator` didn't give any hint that the class is also responsible for parsing CSV.

**Unused code**

`ReadFirstLine` and `ReadFirstLine` don't seem to be used in the current code.

**Streams**

The `StreamReader` class already provides constructors that receive a disk path, so no need to manually create a `FileStream` just to pass it onto the `StreamReader`.

What would however give much more flexibility is for the class to allow the user to provide it with an already constructed `Stream` or `TextReader`. Perhaps the user wants to parse a 100 MB CSV as it's arriving over the wire, without writing it to the disk.

**Parsing CSV**

CSV files allow for quotes to be used so that entries can contain the separator. A parser should be prepared to correctly deal with this.

```
Id,Name,Age
1,John,20
2,"Jack, the second", 21
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need a classic CSV reader there are plenty of good choices in NuGet, if you don't have special requirements, I would just use the common ones.

That said, I made few changes to simplify the code and reduce duplication:

```
public static class CsvReader
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetLines(string path, int limit) => GetLines(path).Take(limit);

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetLines(string path)
    {
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            string line;

            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                yield return line;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<OrderedDictionary> GetCharSeparatedDictionaries(string path, char separator)
    {
        var lineEnumerator = GetLines(path).GetEnumerator();

        if(!lineEnumerator.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        var header = lineEnumerator.Current.Split(separator);

        if(header.Distinct().Count() != header.Length)
            // Handle duplicate headers to prevent exception later.
            yield break;

        while (lineEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var splittedLine = lineEnumerator.Current.Split(separator);

            // Not sure why you would want a dictionary for each line (?)
            var orderedDictionary = new OrderedDictionary();

            // Assuming the file is valid and lines do not contain less fields than the headers. If assumption wrong, need to check.
            for (var i = 0; i < header.Length; i++)
                orderedDictionary.Add(header[i], splittedLine[i]);

            yield return orderedDictionary;
        }
    }
}
```

I appreciate you may have added File.Open to specify a specific sharing mode, if so, just put it back unless there is a suitable overload of `StreamReader`.

There are few weak points for exceptions, I have highlighted some with comments and some with some defensive code, if you have already validated your input file, just remove the checks. ( File not empty on the headers fetching, duplicate headers ).

**LINQ** is a great code saver for the limit method with `Take` and I have removed the duplication.

Name-wise I have removed **CSV** as your dictionary factory method takes any separator and not just a comma, speaking of which, I would also rename the class to something which is less specific.

If you want the class to be testable you can inject the file reader and to mock it.

Good comment from @D. Jurcau about the separator in the content; one more reason to use a good existing CSV parser and then add your logic for the dictionary.

Comment: oh no, a `for` and an `if` without `{}` - your code review needs a code review ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t less distractions from the real code :) I used to write VB.NET, I don't like parenthesis! But drop lines for debugging are a must.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you only use the `LinesReader` to read lines and replace the `ReadFirstLine` with a call to `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
return LinesReader(path).FirstOrDefault();
```

This way you avoid code repetition.

---

In `DictReaderCSV` you can do the same and reuse the reader:

```
var lines = LineReader(path):
var header = lines.FirstOrDefault();
foreach(var line in lines.Skip(1))
{
    ...
}
```

---

Making it *non-static* and providing an abstraction would enable you to use it via Dependency Injection.

Comment: I would avoid calling `FirstOrDefault` and then `Skip`, this will enumerate the collection twice and therefore open the file twice and double up the creation of the FileStream/StreamReader instances.

Comment: @Uno oh, your absolutely right, I meant to add `.ToList()` in the first line but somethow forgot to do it.

Comment: That would work, but it might defeat the purpose of using an iterator to read line by line as it will load the whole file in memory.

Comment: @Uno as the OP didn't say anything about the size of the files I assume they are digestable and only a few kilobytes or megabytes in size - in this case the YAGNI priciple applies ;-) or premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: True, but at this point I would remove the iterator and `ToList()` in the `LinesReader` as it will save the creation of the state machine. (Assuming LineReader is not used somewhere else with a different intent, but that would be odd).

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the overhead of

```
IEnumerable<OrderedDictionary>
```

You are repeating the column names for every row.
There is no check for count not matching in row versus header.

Consider

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>
```

Or

```
IEnumerable<string[]>
```

Somehow report if line does not match header

Split accepts char[]
Might as well support that